# Erro de sintaxe trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tentei criar a trigger abaixo no phpMyAdmin, porém retorna o seguinte erro:

*Mensagens do MySQL :*

#### 1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '' na linha 4

Alguém já passou por isso ou saberia me ajudar?

```
create trigger trg_pagamento before insert on entrega
for each row 
begin
declare pagto int DEFAULT 0;
    select p.cod_status
    into pagto 
    from pagamento p
    where p.cod_pedido = new.cod_pedido;  
    if pagto != 3 then
        null;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: esse if está fazendo alguma coisa? me parece sem sentido, e ainda pode dar erro

Comment: qual é a versão do mysql?

Comment: o if seria pra não realizar a inserção na tabela.....é o mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

O erro acontece pois você não usou o delimitador de instruções do mysql, então quando chega no ; (ponto e vírgula) da linha 4 o mysql entende que o comando está encerrado e que não há necessidade de continuidade.

```
DELIMITER //

-- seu script

//
DELIMITER ;
```

Assim o mysql irá executar tudo que está entre os //.